# onclick JavaScript function gives error: the function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am getting an error when I am calling the onclick function. When I comment the AJAX call, it works fine. If the AJAX call is there, then the function does not work, it will give an error:

> searchUser is not defined

```js
function searchUser() {
    try {
        var userID = document.getElementById("uuid");
        alert(userID);

        .ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/ajax/searchUser.cfm"
            data: {
                method: "searchUser",
                empId: userID
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data != "") {                    
                } else {
                    var tempstr = data.substring(1, data.length - 1);
                    var resultArray = tempStr.split(",");
                    var firstName = resultArray[0];
                    var lastName = resultArray[1];
                    var firstNameElem = document.getElementById("firstName");
                    var lastNameElem = document.getElementById("lastName");
                    firstNameElem.value = firstName;
                    lastNameElem.value = lastName;
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row uniform">
    <div class="12u">
        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="searchUser()" value="Search"> </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to format the code in your questions properly. It makes it much easier for other to read and understand, meaning you'll get quicker and more accurate answers

Comment: Also note that `.ajax()` is incorrect, it should be `$.ajax()`, and you're missing a comma (`,`) after the `url` property

Comment: ... which should give a very obvious syntax error on the console (please check!)

Comment: If your javascript function is defined inside of a (function()) or $(function ()) block, it will not be accessible from your HTML in inline event handlers. Your options are to move the function definition into the global scope, or to handle the click event with jQuery

Comment: Rory, thank you so much. I believe it was because of the two things you had mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Your Browser stops to compile (or better to interprete) the code if there is a Error and that means the function cant be used. Means the error is inside the .ajax. In the comments under your Questions you find the misstakes.

The "try...catch" doesnt catches syntax error, but runtime errors like a stackOverflow (:D)